# XML design Editor Bug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

I want to start develop Android apps on Mac and Windows 7.

I read couple of tutorial instructions on how to install all the android develop workspace:

1. Install Java on my computer.
2. Install all the stuff in the Android SDK Manager.
3. Download an eclipse and run -> Install new software.... to update the eclipse.

I done all of this stuff couple of times on my Mac OS X and windows 7 and there is a bug that continuous all the time : the XML design Editor not show me good the screen or not show it at all, i tried to open new projects and take ready project but it keep doing me this bug.

Did there is something i missed with the install? Did there is specific Eclipse that i should install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about Installation is clearly explained here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing